# Idiomatic in Clojure: (drop 1 str) or (rest str)?

Tags: clojure, idioms

Simple question here for Clojure.  Which is more idiomatic when dealing with strings?  Which is more idiomatic when dealing with other data types?  Which is more efficient?

```
(drop 1 str)
```

or

```
(rest str)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Whatever you're dealing with, `rest` will be more efficient, but the difference will be so trivial as to be uninteresting.

Make sure you know whether you want `rest` or `next`, because in some cases it matters. `rest` is lazier, and is probably right more often, but if you use `rest` when you need `next` the results can be hard to track down.

For strings...neither! Use `subs`, the built-in substring operator:

```
user> (subs "hears" 1)
"ears"
```

`rest` is fine, but it would yield a seq of characters instead of a string; usually you'll find a string easier to deal with, and it's simple enough to turn it back into a seq of characters sometime later.

Comment: Is `drop` just as `lasy` as `rest`? Or is `drop` more like `next`?